# How to delete a db row after cancel button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I want to delete a database row which contains a file name when the user clicks on cancel button. Problem is that it is not deleting the database row. What am I doing wrong that the database row is not being cancelled?

Below is the relevant code of the form:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
  "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
  "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" +     
  "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'><label>" + 
  "<input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>" +
  "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Below is the startImageUpload() function where it starts an file upload and where the cancel button function is stored:

```
  function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){
    $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
      return stopImageUpload(2);
      });     
    return true;
  }
```

Below is the stopImageUpload() function where it displays the cancel message using success and result:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){
  var result = '';
  if (success == 2){
    result = '<span class="imagecemsg"> The file upload was canceled!</span><br/><br/>';
  } else {
    result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
  }         
  return true;   
}
```

Finally below is the imageupload.php script which is linked to the QandATable.php (The script which contains the code above) using iframe and this is where the database row is suppose to be deleted from:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ...//connected to DB
  $result = 0;

  if ($result == 2) {
    $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
                       WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/".
                       mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";
    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
  }
  mysql_close();
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In imageupload.php You declared:

```
$result = 0;
```

Then you say:

```
if ($result == 2)...
```

`$result` is 0 not 2 so the query will not be executed.

Comment: so shall I do `if ($result == 0)...` or do I instead do `$result = ''` and then do `if ($result == 2)... delete db row... else $result = 0;`?

Comment: If you want the delete to function then $result must be 2 i.e. $result = 2;

Comment: But I need $result = 0 for a different message (I didn't include message for $result = 0 in stopImageUpload() function). That is why I tried using an if statement to state if $result = 2, then delete db row. How can it be written so that in php script I can also include $result = 2 so that if this does occur, it will delete the database row?

Comment: I think the reason it is not deleting a db row is because, when a user uploads a file, it inserts a db row, but when the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, technically the file is still uploading in background so it still inserts a row. What I was trying to do was state that if $result = 2 then delete the row which has just been inserted. But what might need to happen is that as a theory is that if $result = 1 and file is moved, then insert row. else if $result = 2 and file is moved then do not insert a row. What do you think?